# Execute count(*) on a group-by result-set

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to do a nice SQL statement inside a stored procedure.

I looked at the issue of seeing the number of days that events happened between two dates.
My example is sales orders: for this month, how many days did we have sales orders?

Suppose this setup:

```
CREATE TABLE  `sandbox`.`orders` (
  `year` int,
  `month` int,
  `day` int,
  `desc` varchar(255) 
) 

INSERT INTO orders (year, month, day, desc)  
VALUES (2009,1,1, 'New Years Resolution 1')
      ,(2009,1,1, 'Promise lose weight')
      ,(2009,1,2, 'Bagel')
      ,(2009,1,12, 'Coffee to go')
```

For this in-data the result should be 3, since there has been three days with sale.
The best solution I found is as below.

However, making a temporary table, counting that then dropping it seemes excess. It "should" be possible in one statement.

Anyone who got a "nicer" solution then me?

/L

```
SELECT [Year], [Month], [Day]
INTO #Some_Days
FROM Quarter
WHERE Start >= '2009-01-01' AND [End] < '2009-01-16'
GROUP BY [Year], [Month], [Day]

SELECT count(*) from #Some_Days
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Apologies if I'm misunderstanding the question, but perhaps you could do something like this, as an option:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT(SomeColumn)
       FROM MyTable
      WHERE Something BETWEEN 100 AND 500
      GROUP BY SomeColumn) MyTable
```

... to get around the temp-table creation and disposal?

Comment: This I got to work on the MSSQL-server.

    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
    ( SELECT DISTINCT year , month , day
  FROM Orders
  WHERE Start >= '2009-1-1' AND [End] < '2009-1-16'
    ) myTableDummy 

I tried similar myself, never realized that "myTableDummy" was needed though. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the FROM (SELECT ...) type of subquery always have to use a temporary table anyway?  At any rate, it's still fast.

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic options which I can see.  One is to group everything up in a sub query, then count those distinct rows (Christian Nunciato's answer).  The second is to combine the multiple fields and count distinct values of that combined value.

In this case, the following formula coverts the three fields into a single datetime.

```
DATEADD(YEAR, [Quarter].Year, DATEADD(MONTH, [Quarter].Month, DATEADD(DAY, [Quarter].DAY, 0), 0), 0)
```

Thus, COUNT(DISTINCT [formula]) will give the answer you need.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATEADD(YEAR, [Quarter].Year, DATEADD(MONTH, [Quarter].Month, DATEADD(DAY, [Quarter].DAY, 0), 0), 0))
FROM
    Quarter
WHERE
    [Quarter].Start >= '2009-01-01'
    AND [Quarter].End < '2009-01-16'
```

I usually use the sub query route, but depending on what you're doing, indexes, size of table, simplicity of the formula, etc, this Can be faster...

Dems.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT day) FROM orders 
WHERE (year, month) = (2009, 1);
```

Actually, I don't know if TSQL supports tuple comparisons, but you get the idea.

`COUNT(DISTINCT expr)` is standard SQL and should work everywhere.

Comment: How does that (year, month) thing work? I've never seen that.

Comment: It's supposed to be equivalent to: (year=2009 AND month=1).  But I can never remember which RDBMS brands support it and which don't.  And some don't optimize it very well.  Probably best to avoid.

Comment: Oh, tuples. I lied, I guess I have seen those. Nice reminder that they exist though.

Comment: Nice solution! SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT year, month, day) FROM orders Solves it on mysql. By some reason I cannot get TSQL to accept it.  :(

Comment: Then try `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT year * 10000 + month * 100 + day) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You should use nested Select statements. Inner one should contain group by clause, and the outer one should count it. I think "Christian Nunciato" helped you already.

```
Select Count(1) As Quantity
From
(    
    SELECT [Year], [Month], [Day]
    INTO #Some_Days
    FROM Quarter
    WHERE Start >= '2009-01-01' AND [End] < '2009-01-16'
    GROUP BY [Year], [Month], [Day]
) AS InnerResultSet
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [Year], [Month], [Day]
FROM Quarter
WHERE Start >= '2009-01-01' AND [End] < '2009-01-16'
GROUP BY [Year], [Month], [Day]
COMPUTE COUNT(*)
```